# Adding place markers to Google Map

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-maps

I have this code below which draws a line on a google maps from co-ordinates from an XML file.
However I want it to show the first co-ordinate and the last coordinate with a place marker as well. I managed to do this without drawing the line by following the steps here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?csw=1

but can't seem to be able to integrate the 2. i.e Draw the line and have place markers at the start and finish.

I'm sure its just a tiny bit of code I have to add too the code I already have below but I'm wrecking my train trying to work it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

function load() {
    var point;
                    var flightPlanCoordinates=new Array();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.431, -3.202),
                zoom: 9,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                 },
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                }
            });

            downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;

        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            flightPlanCoordinates[i]=point;

          }

          var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);

      });

        }

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
    function doNothing() {}

 //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you posted above, you are never adding your markers to the map, which is done with the following code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map, //The Map Object
  position: point //The location of the Marker
});
```

You would want to put this statement into your for loop as you iterate through the GPS points,  and if it is the first iteration or the last iteration through the loop, than add your marker. You can than draw your polyline after the loop like you are doing in your posted example.